Making REST call to a service installed in the same org
How would I authenticate to a REST service from a Flow Action when the REST service is installed in the same Salesforce org where my Apex is running?
The scenario is that I have written a custom flow action in Apex using @invocable method. This flow action needs to make a callout to a REST Service that is included in a package that is installed in the same Salesforce org that the flow action is running in.
I could call the Global method contained in the installed package that implements the REST service but that would create a dependency on the installed package's namespace, which I cannot have.
I cannot use session IDs since they are not available in the flow.
Do I have to go completely through the process of creating Named Creds, External Credentials, specifying a Authentication Provider, etc?
